# How do I logout of a website using R after logging into a website using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I have worked out how to log into a website from the following:

1. https://riptutorial.com/r/example/23955/using-rvest-when-login-is-required

Login code:
login <-"https://www.mysite.com.au/"

```
pgsession <- html_session(login)
pgform    <- html_form(pgsession)[[2]]  #

filled_form <- set_values(pgform, 
                          'ctl00$Content$Login'    = "bangbang", 
                          'ctl00$Content$Password' = "xxxxxx")

submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
```

I'm now looking to solve the next problem on how exactly to logout of the website from R.

- The website that I log into has a logout button, which is what I use when logging out via browser

I'm still very new using `rvest` and don't have a proper understanding of it all. Hence, would appreciate detailed help:

1. How to work out the logout string (I looked in the console and `XHR` in firefox but not sure which one to use)
2. What command I should use to logout

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: How you log out will differ by why webpage you are interacting with. There's not one way to log out of every website. In most cases logging in probably only works per session so if you just abandon the session, you probably don't really need to explicitly logout. But again, it depends on the specific website you are working with.

Comment: Is there a way to manually `abandon` the session (forgive my ignorance)?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what code you've actually run to see how you might undo it.

Comment: login code added, thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: You could delete the `pgsession` variable so it can't be reused. `rm(pgsession)`

Comment: So my problem is that the website allows only one login. If I'm logged in via R, then I need to wait 30 mins for the session to expire till I can log back in via browser :(

Comment: Then you will need to reverse engineer that particular website to figure out how it’s logout mechanism works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a process that after login, finds and stores the URL used to logout.

```r
myfunc <- function(user, pass) {
  sess <- rvest::html_session(myurl)
  ############################################################
  ### all of this is particular to the URL that *I* am scraping ... adapt for your own
  loginform <- sess %>%
    rvest::html_nodes("form") %>%
    rvest::html_form()
  formtypes <- lapply(loginform[[1]]$fields, `[[`, "type")
  formuser <- names(Filter(function(a) a == "text", formtypes))
  formpass <- names(Filter(function(a) a == "password", formtypes))
  formsubmit <- names(Filter(function(a) a == "submit", formtypes))
  formfields <- setNames(list(user, pass), c(formuser, formpass))
  formfields <- do.call(rvest::set_values, c(list(loginform[[1]]), formfields))
  loggedin <- rvest::submit_form(sess, formfields, formsubmit)
  # ... okay, now I'm logged in

  ############################################################
  ### this next section is pertinent to your need to find and eventually
  ### use the logout link in your html session
  # prepare for eventual logout
  logoutnodes <- rvest::html_nodes(loggedin, "a")
  logoutlinks <- rvest::html_attr(logoutnodes, "href")
  logouttexts <- rvest::html_text(logoutnodes)
  logoutind <- grep("log.*out", logouttexts, ignore.case = TRUE)

  logouturl <- logoutlinks[ logoutind[[1]] ]
  # ignore errors on logout attempt
  on.exit({
    # this code executes when 'myfunc' exits ... for whatever reason
    tryCatch(rvest::jump_to(loggedin, logouturl),
             error = function(e) NULL)
  }, add = TRUE)

  ############################################################
  # now we can do the real purpose of myfunc
  # ...
  # ...
}
```

Granted, this is rather verbose and drawn-out, but with *my* website, the variables are unpredictable and cluttered and such ... so when I found that this method worked, I stuck with it.

In your case, the *premise* is that you

1. find the "log out" link and remember it; and
2. use `on.exit` to `rvest::jump_to(sess, logouturl)`

Comment: Fabulous! Thanks you so much, used your code/ideas to workout my logout function.